# How to join an associated table when the joined table can have one or more records?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables:

```
posts (id, published_at)
posts_images (id, post_id, image_url(null or url string))
```

Each post has at least 1 posts_images record and can have more than 1 as well.

My Goal: query shows me the % of posts that have 1 or more images, broken down by week (7 days) ago.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  floor(datediff(p.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
        date(min(p.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
        date(max(p.created_at)) AS "Date End",
        count(DISTINCT p.id) AS "Posts in Cohort"
        count(pc.image_url) / count(p.id) AS "Post w 1 or more Images Ratio",
FROM    posts p
        INNER JOIN posts_images pc
            ON p.id = pc.post_id
WHERE p.published_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```

The query runs fine and outputs data but I'm not sure if I'm performing the JOIN correctly given that posts have 1 or more posts_images. I'm worried that SQL is picking the first posts_images record and not looking at all of them.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are better off with two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT  floor(datediff(p.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago,
        date(min(p.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
        date(max(p.created_at)) AS "Date End",
        count(*) as  "Posts in Cohort",
        avg(has_image) as "Post w 1 or more Images Ratio",
FROM (SELECT p.id, p.created_at,
             ( MAX(pi.image_url) IS NOT NULL ) as has_image
      FROM posts p JOIN
           posts_images pi
           ON p.id = pi.post_id
      WHERE p.published_at IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY p.id
     ) p
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by finding cases of multiple images:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM posts_images
    GROUP BY post_id
    HAVING ct > 1
```

Then I would go to `posts` to find what week is involved:

```
SELECT  floor(datediff(p.created_at, curdate()) / 7) AS weeks_ago
        date(min(p.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
        date(max(p.created_at)) AS "Date End",
        count(*) AS "Posts in Cohort"
        ROUND(SUM(x.ct) / count(*), 3) AS "Post w 1 or more Images Ratio",
    FROM ( .. the query above .. ) AS x
    JOIN posts AS p  ON x.post_id = p.id
    GROUP BY weeks_ago
    ORDER BY weeks_ago DESC;
```

The advantage over your approach is that the intermediate temp table is smaller (one row per post vs one row per image).

Potential problem:

- Date Start-End may not be exactly days.  This can be fixed by working backwards from the `FLOOR` to get start/end of the "week".
- Missing weeks.  This would require another table with all the weeks, plus a messy `LEFT JOIN`.